# Can't browse to Azure Cloud Service site URL

Tags: azure, service, cloud

I've deployed an Azure cloud service (*not* a web site) and I'm trying to access it via a browser.  When I attempt to browse to the 'site url', it times out.  Nor can I ping the Public VIP listed in the Azure dashboard for the service.  Hrm.

Now, if I log on to one of the instance VMs, fire up IIS Manager and find the IP address it has listed for the web site, I *can* browse to that one.  Weird.

I'm sure I'm just thick and am missing something simple here.  Can anyone point me in a good direction to make my service's site url browsable?

The service definition I'm using is https://github.com/NuGet/NuGetGallery/blob/master/src/NuGetGallery.Cloud/ServiceDefinition.csdef, if that helps.

Comment: I've got a similar issue - my cloudapp.net url doesn't even resolve. Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Unfortunately, I never did.  Thanks for checking and best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can check the "endpoints" tab under the cloud service section of the Azure portal.

There should be an endpoint listed for HTTP that redirects to your VM. You can forward different public ports on the cloud service to individual ports on specific VMs within the cloud service.

Comment: Thanks for your reply!  This is a cloud service deployed directly to Azure (i.e. I didn't create a VM beforehand), so I have no access to the endpoints via the Azure portal.  :(